# Is it possible to install Chromium on Android?

Tags: browser, apk, chromium

I really like the Chromium browser, it's quite speedy, but I can't find any functioning downloads for Android.

All the sites I've tried so far have the following error while trying to install the APK file:

> ### Parse Error
>
> There is a problem parsing the package.

I've tried [Download Chromium](https://download-chromium.appspot.com/?platform=Android) (which was invaluable in getting Chromium working on my Desktop) and [Github's paul99/clank](https://github.com/paul99/clank), but neither source seems to work.

Does anyone know where I can download Chromium? (*not* Google Chrome!)
I'm running a non-rooted Android 2.3.4 on Droid X.

Comment: Chrome only supports Android 4.0+, so I would not be surprised if that is also the case for the Chromium builds you are trying to install (unless they are heavily altered). It may be failing to parse the package because it declares things in the manifest that Android 2.3.4 does not implement, so this could very well be impossible barring significant code modifications.

Comment: You could possibly get Chromium if you install a custom mod that has it built in.

Comment: I think you can only get it in a newer version of android

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned on [Eldarerathis' comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/48663/is-it-possible-to-install-chromium-on-android#comment65624_48663), no matter what, you are going to need a newer version of Android, which probably means (CyanogenMod will only get you to 2.3.7) that you'll need a newer phone.

The good news is that from 4.0+ it only gets easier to easily run Chromium safely on Android. For Android 4.4, there's a free and open-source app [getChromium](https://github.com/andDevW/getChromium) that installs/updates the Chromium browser on Android.

**FULL DISCLOSURE**: A lack of trust in http*://chromium.woolyss.com, and other, equally sketchy non-Google vendors giving away "Chromium APK", together with a passion for malware-free Chromium APK was actually what motivated me to put together [getChromium](https://github.com/andDevW/getChromium) as an open-source means of getting builds directly from Google's repository over here: https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-continuous/Android.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible, **but** you need devices running on Android 4.1 JellyBean or above (as of testing). Otherwise, you'll get "Parse error" message when installing it.

---

Note: I'm using the APK from [here](http://chromium.woolyss.com/#android). I checked the content of the manifest using [`aapt`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191762/how-to-view-androidmanifest-xml-from-apk-file#) and on line #31649:

```
E: uses-sdk (line=12)
  A: android:minSdkVersion(0x0101020c)=(type 0x10)0x10
  A: android:targetSdkVersion(0x01010270)=(type 0x10)0x16
```

Note the value of [`android:minSdkVersion`](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html#minsdkversion), it's `0x10`, which is `16` in decimal, and it corresponds to [Android 4.1 JellyBean](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.1.html).

Answer (score 2):

You could try building it yourself, following the instructions on the official site: https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/android-build-instructions

Again, though, you will need a higher version of Android.

Answer (score 1):

Chromium for Android can be found [here](https://storage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-continuous/index.html?path=Android/32eaa6c2911c647846e31071e4e02efe56c8cd1c/) (multiple and platform specific versions available too).